# Check if UI elements/RectTransform are overlapping

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, rect

I'd like to know how I check whether two UI Panels on my Unity Canvas are overlapping each other.

Currently I am doing this by comparing the canvas elements Rects

**Canvas Settings**

- Render Mode: Screen Space - Camera
- Pixel Perfect: [Yes]
- Render Camera: Main Camera
- Plane Distance: 100
- Sorting Layer: Default
- Order In Layer: 0

**Canvas Scaler Settings**

- UI Scale Mode: Constant Pixel Size
- Scale Factor: 1
- Reference Pixels Per Unit: 100

**Code I am using to check**

```
[Header("Check For Overlap")]
public RectTransform PlayerBar;
public RectTransform LeftBar;
public Rect RectOne;
public Rect RectTwo;
public bool overlapping;

//Check if the two canvas element Rects overlap each other

public void CheckForOverlap()
{
    overlapping = false;
    // Convert Canvas RectTransforms to World Rects
    RectOne = GetWorldRect(LeftBar);
    RectTwo = GetWorldRect(PlayerBar);

    if (RectOne.Overlaps(RectTwo))
    {
        overlapping = true;
    }
}


public Rect GetWorldRect(RectTransform rt)
{
    //  Get World corners, take top left
    Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
    rt.GetWorldCorners(corners);
    Vector3 topLeft = corners[0];

    // Rect Size ... I'm not sure if this is working correctly?
    Vector2 size = new Vector2(rt.rect.size.x, rt.rect.size.y);
    return new Rect(topLeft, size);
}
```

**What happens**

'Overlapping' bool instantly changes to true.

The Rect One returns as (example)

X -7.5, Y 2.5
W 98.5, H 164.1667

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Convert the `RectTransform` to `Rect` then check if it overlaps.

Here is a simple function that can do that:

```
bool rectOverlaps(RectTransform rectTrans1, RectTransform rectTrans2)
{
    Rect rect1 = new Rect(rectTrans1.localPosition.x, rectTrans1.localPosition.y, rectTrans1.rect.width, rectTrans1.rect.height);
    Rect rect2 = new Rect(rectTrans2.localPosition.x, rectTrans2.localPosition.y, rectTrans2.rect.width, rectTrans2.rect.height);

    return rect1.Overlaps(rect2);
}
```

**Usage**:

```
public RectTransform uiRect1;
public RectTransform uiRect2;

void Update()
{
    if (rectOverlaps(uiRect1, uiRect2))
    {
        Debug.Log("Overlaps");
    }else
    {
        Debug.Log("Does not Overlap");
    }
}
```

Even better, make it an extension method:

```
public static class ExtensionMethod
{
    public static bool rectOverlaps(this RectTransform rectTrans1, RectTransform rectTrans2)
    {
        Rect rect1 = new Rect(rectTrans1.localPosition.x, rectTrans1.localPosition.y, rectTrans1.rect.width, rectTrans1.rect.height);
        Rect rect2 = new Rect(rectTrans2.localPosition.x, rectTrans2.localPosition.y, rectTrans2.rect.width, rectTrans2.rect.height);

        return rect1.Overlaps(rect2);
    }
}
```

Now, you can do

```
public RectTransform uiRect1;
public RectTransform uiRect2;

void Update()
{
    if (uiRect1.rectOverlaps(uiRect2))
    {

    }

    //OR

    if (uiRect2.rectOverlaps(uiRect1))
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this was really useful. Especially the added tip for an extension method

Comment: `RectTransform` already has `rect` object, wouldn't using it be less memory expensive?

Comment: This only works if both objects have the same parent. How would you do this if this is not a guarantee?

Comment: I don't see any projection in screen coordinates - you are only ignoring the z coordinate. This should projected first to screen coordinates.

Comment: does not work if parent is anchored elswhere

Answer (score 8):

Updated version considering scale of the rectTransform.

```
public static class RectTransformExtensions
{

    public static bool Overlaps(this RectTransform a, RectTransform b) {
        return a.WorldRect().Overlaps(b.WorldRect());
    }
    public static bool Overlaps(this RectTransform a, RectTransform b, bool allowInverse) {
        return a.WorldRect().Overlaps(b.WorldRect(), allowInverse);
    }

    public static Rect WorldRect(this RectTransform rectTransform) {
        Vector2 sizeDelta = rectTransform.sizeDelta;
        float rectTransformWidth = sizeDelta.x * rectTransform.lossyScale.x;
        float rectTransformHeight = sizeDelta.y * rectTransform.lossyScale.y;

        Vector3 position = rectTransform.position;
        return new Rect(position.x - rectTransformWidth / 2f, position.y - rectTransformHeight / 2f, rectTransformWidth, rectTransformHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: this script is so much better in my testing. it detects very well. thank you.

Comment: This doesn't work when anchors are not in the same position because `sizeDelta` will be zero.

Answer (score 0):

This from the first answer (thank you!) but I updated so that it works regardless of where the pivot is.

```
public static class RectTransformExtensions
{
    
        public static bool Overlaps(this RectTransform a, RectTransform b) {
            return a.WorldRect().Overlaps(b.WorldRect());
        }
        public static bool Overlaps(this RectTransform a, RectTransform b, bool allowInverse) {
            return a.WorldRect().Overlaps(b.WorldRect(), allowInverse);
        }

        public static Rect WorldRect(this RectTransform rectTransform)
        {
            Vector2 sizeDelta = rectTransform.sizeDelta;
            Vector2 pivot = rectTransform.pivot;
            
            float rectTransformWidth = sizeDelta.x * rectTransform.lossyScale.x;
            float rectTransformHeight = sizeDelta.y * rectTransform.lossyScale.y;

            //With this it works even if the pivot is not at the center
            Vector3 position =rectTransform.TransformPoint(rectTransform.rect.center);
            float x = position.x - rectTransformWidth * 0.5f;
            float y = position.y - rectTransformHeight * 0.5f;
            
            return new Rect(x,y, rectTransformWidth, rectTransformHeight);
        }
    
}
```