# Unity alway getting false with Physics2D.OverlapArea

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to check if an drag-able Image is touching a panel in a scene. I have attached a script to the image and I want to do the check when the drag ends.

However I am always getting `False` returned for the `Physics2D.OverlapArea` even though the image is touching the panel. I have added a new layer to the panel. From the many examples I have seen I seem to be doing it correctly

```
public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Vector3[] corners = new Vector3[4];
    GetComponent<RectTransform>().GetWorldCorners(corners);

    var bottomLeft = corners[0];
    var topRight = corners[2];

    bool panelCollider = Physics2D.OverlapArea(bottomLeft, topRight, 9);

    Debug.Log(panelCollider);

    if (panelCollider)
    {
        Debug.Log("Image is over panel");
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't believe OverlapArea works with UI elements.  Also your panel would need to have a collder, and be in world space... (Hence the reason you had to call GetWorldCorners)

Comment: Is there a way to detect if a UI is touching another game object?

Comment: Is the other GameObject a UI object as well?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42043017/check-if-ui-elements-recttransform-are-overlapping

Comment: Yes it is a `GameObject` with `RecTransform` is use as a parent